# Eloquent foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a 3 models relationship in Laravel 6 and Foreign keys won't work, becouse i get this error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`product_id` = 1 and `products`.`product_id` is not null limit 1)'
```

I have a 3 table (the tables are: users, cartItems, products) relationship . The foreign key that refers user's id into cartItems seamns to work, but the one that refers product's id into cartItems don't .

**The cartItems table migration:**

```
        Schema::create('cart_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');

    });
```

**The products table migraton:**

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('productName');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

The cartItem model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class cartItem extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

The product model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded  = [];

    public function cartItem() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

The user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function cartItems() {
        return $this->hasMany(cartItem::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the query where you are getting the exception

Comment: What's the sequence of creation of migration make sure users and products table created before carts table

Comment: You can get stack trace by using php artisan migrate -v post that

Comment: The query that give me the exception is: cartItem::find(1)->product

Comment: Please share your cartitem and product model

Comment: Updated my question, sorry for late update

Comment: The  sequence of creation of migration is determinated by what ? How can I change that sequence ?

Comment: try `$table->bigIncrements('id');` in your migrations

Comment: I need to declare a Primary Key on id column if i use $table->bigIncrements('id'); ?

Comment: never mind, i'd never seen that shorthand before.  for your foreign key to work, make sure your products table gets migrated first.  migrations are in order of filename

Comment: The order of migration is: users, products, cartItems .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifying `xxxxx_id` columns in the cartItems table, then cartItem is the *child* model, not the parent.  Otherwise you might need to rethink your relationships.

To fix as-is (and leave the migration the same), change your Eloquent relationships to:

```php
// Product.php
public function cartItems() {
    return $this->hasMany(cartItem::class);
}
```

and its inverse:

```php
// cartItem.php
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
```

expects the `products` table to be created already.  Migrations run in filename order, so make sure your products table migration has an earlier "date" stamp than the cart_items table migration.

Comment: The order of  creating tables is: users, products and after those two cart_items .